# Filtered GeoJson geometry not working properly on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, leaflet

I'm using filter() to return only a Estate (UF) from my country, using Axios:

```
async created() {
    await axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fititnt/gis-dataset-brasil/master/mesorregiao/geojson/mesorregiao.json')
      .then((response) => {
          const myUf = 'GO'
          const data = response.data.features.filter(item => item.properties.UF = myUf)
          console.log(response.data.features.filter(item => item.properties.UF = myUf))
          this.geojson = data;
        }
      )
  }
```

Working just fine, got all my data on log! But my my keep showing all GeoJson data, there's some config to do next?
All regions being colored, but I just want the regions I filtered to be colored.
Didn't found anything on LeaftLet doc and Vue-Leaflet!

[image: console.log from data]

As asked, here's my code:
my data(), where I call geojson on vue

```
data() {
    return {
      zoom: 6.4,
      center: latLng(-15.7745457, -48.3575684),
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | TRE-GO',
      geojson: null,
      fillColor: "#6a0dad",
    }
  },
```

Here's my L-map component:

```
<l-map
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      style="height: 500px; width: 100%"
    >
      <l-tile-layer
        :url="url"
        :attribution="attribution"
      />
      <l-geo-json :geojson="geojson"
                  :options-style="styleFunction"/>


    </l-map>
```

Comment: Please share your code, where you add the geojson to your map ... [Geojson-Tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) look into the last section `filter`

Comment: @FalkeDesign Code on post edit! Thanks for Doc Link, I'll give a try on `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filtering function does not actually filter anything  unfortunately, because it does an assignment (1 equal sign) instead of a comparison (3 or 2 equal signs):

```
item => item.properties.UF = myUf
```

...should be:

```
item => item.properties.UF === myUf
```